# OneDrive resumable upload in iOS

Tags: nsurlsession, onedrive, nsurlsessionuploadtask, http-content-range

I'm having issue with resumable upload, using URLSession in iOS.
Everything works, except the resumable upload. 
The session upload creation works, I've got my uploadUrl back, so I simply start an URLSessionUploadTask:

```
let url = URL(string: urlUploadString)!
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "PUT"
urlRequest.setValue("bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
let task = urlsession.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, fromFile: localFile)
task.resume()
```

The transfer goes through, however, in the end, I receive a http code 400 with the response:

```
["error": {
    code = invalidRequest;
    message = "Invalid Content-Range header value";
}]
```

The thing, I can't set the Content-Range header per chunk, because iOS handles the upload, not me. And it doesn't seem to set Content-Range header automatically for each chunk sent.

Comment: It should be Authorization (U.S. spelling, not U.K.).

Comment: It's my browser spelling check fault. In Xcode, the spelling is right.

Comment: It seems I have to create an uploadTask EACH time I upload a fragment of the file.